# flash builder - export build is generating airi file instead of air

Tags: air, flash-builder

This is my first time I ever created an air installer. When I clicked on "Export release build..." and clicked on finish, it is creating "projectname.AIRI" file instead of "projectname.air" file.

I confirm below check

I did not change the default name
Tried to find using what an airi can open with, but there is nothing as such
Renamed airi to air and tried to open the file (icon has changed to air installer) but it gave me error "corrupted installer"

Can some one help me what to do? Is it that complicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options in the "Digitial Signature" window

1. Export and sign an AIR file with an digital certificate
2. Export an intermidiate AIRI file that will be signed later

The options are very clear. I have not read the options clearly and went ahead to option 2 which creates AIRI file as it says.

I overseen the "Create..." button next to the "browse" button to select the digital certificate and I thought I must have a digitial certificate already and I dont have one.

Its simple, just click on the create button to create one certificate and the same certificate can be used for other pprojects as well.